# Is there a way to bind using partially matching string?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframes:

```
State           County              Population
North Carolina  Anson County        26948
North Carolina  Ashe County         27281
North Carolina  Avery County        17797
```

and

```
County          Violent Crime
Avery           10
Beaufort        30
Berty           12
```

I would normally bind them using
`bind(df1, df2, by = 'County')`
but the second dataframe doesn't have the work 'county' at the end while the first one does. Additionally, the second dataframe is missing several observations, so they don't align perfectly. Is there a way to bind them based on the first word in county?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
regex_left_join(df1, df2, by = 'County')%>%
      select(County = County.x, everything(), -County.y)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(State = c("North Carolina", "North Carolina", 
"North Carolina"), County = c("Anson County", "Ashe County", 
"Avery County"), Population = c(26948L, 27281L, 17797L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(County = c("Avery", "Beaufort", "Berty"), 
 ViolentCrime = c(10L, 
30L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```